# My C++11 test show that sort(vector<string>) is even slower than C++03, any error?

Tags: c++, performance, sorting, c++11, move

With right value reference and move semantics, C++11's swap/sort speed, should be equal or greater than C++03. So I designed a simple experiment to test this.

I compile and run it with -O2, with c++03 and c++11 standard.

```
$g++ test.cpp -O2 && ./a.out
10240000 end construction
sort 10240000 spent1.40035

$g++ test.cpp -O2 -std=c++11 && ./a.out
10240000 end construction
sort 10240000 spent2.25684
```

So it seems with C++11 enabled, program is slower.
I'm on a very new mac and gcc environment:

```
$gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Below is source code:

```
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cstdio>
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;
string randomString()
{
    const size_t scale=600;
    char ret[scale];
    for(size_t i=0;i<scale;++i)
    {
        double rand0to1=(double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
        ret[i]=(char)rand0to1*92+33;
    }
    return ret;
}
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    const size_t scale=10240000;
    vector<string> vs;
    vs.reserve(scale);
    for(size_t i=0;i<scale;++i)
    {
        vs.push_back(randomString());
    }
    cout<<vs.size()<<" end construction\n";
    clock_t begin=clock();
    sort(vs.begin(),vs.end());
    clock_t end=clock();
    double duration=(double)(end-begin)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout<<"sort "<<scale<<" spent"<<duration<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Any error with my program or understanding, how to explain my test result?

Really need your expertise on this!

Comment: Instead of a randomized input set you should have a fixed set of data to compare the sorting speed.

Comment: Your `randomString` function is really weird and broken.

Comment: ... such a fixed set of data can of course be generated using `random()`, but the seed should be fixed so that you do a fair comparison. Can you try that and [edit] the result into the question?

Comment: I got bad_alloc on this code in MSVC2015

Comment: C++03 strings are typically implemented as copy-on-write, C++11 strings are not. Apples to oranges.

Comment: @Starl1ght: Are you compiling in 64 bit mode?

Comment: Also, I think Your char array needs a null-termination too.

Comment: @n.m. Has libstdc++ also moved away from copy-on-write?

Comment: @YanZhou It seems so, since the cxx11 ABI change.

Comment: @n.m. That's good to know

Comment: @n.m. - copy-on-write wasn't all that common. That's why it was easy to ban it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test code has several issues.

1. The string you generate in `ret` is not null terminated so it will contain garbage from the stack which is likely to change with compiler settings. This the most likely cause of your strange results: the c++11 version sorting longer strings.
2. Your casts lead to strings which are all identical. Not an actual problem with measurements but probably not what you're interested in testing.
3. You should not use a truly random seed for benchmarking. You want to produce the same strings on every run to get reproducibility.

This fixed version of the code:

```
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cstdio>
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;
string randomString()
{
    const size_t scale=600;
    char ret[scale];
    for(size_t i=0;i<scale;++i)
    {
        double rand0to1=(double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
        ret[i]=(char)(rand0to1*92+33);
    }
    ret[scale-1] = 0;
    return ret;
}
int main()
{
    srand(1);
    const size_t scale=10240000;
    vector<string> vs;
    vs.reserve(scale);
    for(size_t i=0;i<scale;++i)
    {
        vs.push_back(randomString());
    }
    cout<<vs.size()<<" end construction\n";
    clock_t begin=clock();
    sort(vs.begin(),vs.end());
    clock_t end=clock();
    double duration=(double)(end-begin)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout<<"sort "<<scale<<" spent "<<duration<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

produces what I believe you were expecting:

```
$ g++ -O2 -std=c++03 test.cpp && ./a.out
10240000 end construction
sort 10240000 spent 10.8765

$ g++ -O2 -std=c++11 test.cpp && ./a.out
10240000 end construction
sort 10240000 spent 8.72834
```

By the way, g++ from Xcode on a mac is actually clang. But the results are similar:

```
$ clang++ -O2 -std=c++03 test.cpp && ./a.out
10240000 end construction
sort 10240000 spent 10.9408

$ clang++ -O2 -std=c++11 test.cpp && ./a.out
10240000 end construction
sort 10240000 spent 8.33261
```

Tested with g++ 6.2.1 and clang 3.9.0. The `-std=c++03` switch is important as without it, g++ compiles in a mode which gives the fast times.

Comment: g++ 6 defaults to `-std=gnu++14`.

Comment: In addition, he should do multiple iterations of the sort with each execution, and take the average.